# How did Marshal Pentecost know he and Chuck Hansen were drift compatible?

Tags: plot-explanation, pacific-rim

In the final battle of Pacific Rim when Herc Hansen had been injured Marshal Pentecost and Chuck Hansen pilot the Striker Eureka into the ocean.

Chuck had concerns that the pair would not be drift compatible but Pentecost brushed them aside saying "You're your father's son".

How did Pentecost know he and Chuck could drift together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is established right away that drift-compatibility is something that is based on a kind of equality in spirit as it exists between what one could more poetically call "soul mates" (like *Raleigh* and *Mako*) or brothers (like the *Beckets*) or father and son (like the *Hansens*). So given that *Marshal Pentecost* and *Herc Hansen* were once drift-compatible and *Herc* and his son were drift-compatible it is not a large stretch that there is a high chance for a transitive drift-compatibility between *Stacker* and *Chuck*.

There is on the one hand of course a genetic compatibility between *Herc* and his son, which *Marshal Pentecost* could have meant with the sentence *"You're your father's son"*. But even more likely he probably meant to say that *Chuck* is in fact pretty equal to his father in his spirit and mind, or maybe how his father once was in his youth (or when he was riding the *Jaegers* together with *Stacker*), or said more colloquially that "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree".

Comment: "when he was riding the Jaegers together with Stacker" ah, that was the bit I'd missed!

Comment: Very good answer Christain! +1

Comment: I didn't realize Pentecost had ever co-piloted with Stacker, I thought they just [served alongside](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Herc_Hansen) each other! This makes sense now.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I admit that I should maybe recheck this part, having now two viewers not remembering it. But I'm pretty sure it's stated explicitly.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson But, didn't Pentecost say that on his last ride, he had to pilot his Jaeger alone, and also got irradiated in the process? I always assumed that his co-pilot died on the process (probably because of irradiation, since Kaijus weren't strong enough to beat them).